# How to read pub sub alerts using python in cloud functions and read the json

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-developers-console, securitycenter

I am trying to read the alerts from pub/sub topics message which is integrated with the security center in the GCP console using the Cloud function with python code. Is there any way to read the alerts resource type and check its status and make changes to that resource using python?
Since I have tried searching all docs I didn't get the proper doc on this part. Can anyone guide me on this?

```
import base64
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
  pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
  print(pubsub_message)
```

Comment: Yes, you can do all those things in Python. It depends on the resource type and what you want to achieve, but most of the time, libraries exist.

Comment: could you please paste me the url which has docs related this query

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. The Google Cloud doc is great, you could find whatever you want. If you have a blocker, come back here and we will help y ou